# Should I implement all pages Angular.js if I use Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Angular.js is often introduced as a "single page application".
I want to integrate Angular.js with Rails, but I don't how.

I expect to use Angular.js to implement all pages?
Is it OK to implement some pages with Angular.js and some pages with Rails?